# Modify/parse declared regex variable into a new regex in JS

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a top-level regex variable in JS based on which I later need to do some narrower checks as well for other criteria.

```
var pattern = /^(EAC|MSC|SRC|IOE|LIN|WAC|NBC|YSC|SSC|ESC|WSC|ZAR|ZBO|ZOL|ZLA|ZNY|ZSF|ZNK|ZHN|ZCH|ZMI|ZDF|ZGA|ZTB)(\*|\d)\d{9}$/;
```

My new pattern needs to be all Z-prefixed entries here and without the final digits. But I don't want to redefine a new regex variable as

```
var pattern2 = /^(ZAR|ZBO|ZOL|ZLA|ZNY|ZSF|ZNK|ZHN|ZCH|ZMI|ZDF|ZGA|ZTB)$/;
```

It's possible that the original top-level pattern may change and I don't want to maintain/duplicate separate variables. If they add a new supported `Z..`, that should percolate down to the second "Z-only, No-Digits" regex automatically. Is it possible to modify or parse this similar to a string, and have it become a new regex?

Comment: You can perform string operations on `pattern.toString().substring(1,pattern.toString().length-1)` and convert the result back as `pattern2 = new RegExp(manipulated_string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Update

Simply use [`RegExp#source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) to convert the regex back to string:

```js
console.config({ maximize: true });

const pattern = /^(EAC|MSC|SRC|IOE|LIN|WAC|NBC|YSC|SSC|ESC|WSC|ZAR|ZBO|ZOL|ZLA|ZNY|ZSF|ZNK|ZHN|ZCH|ZMI|ZDF|ZGA|ZTB)(\*|\d)\d{9}$/;
console.log({ pattern, source: pattern.source });

const alternatives = pattern.source.match(/\(([^()]+?)\)/)[1].split('|');
const zPrefixed = alternatives.filter(alt => alt.startsWith('Z'));
console.log({ alternatives, zPrefixed });

const pattern2 = new RegExp(`^(${zPrefixed.join('|')})$`)
console.log(pattern2);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

## Original

Sure you can, just extract those to variables and use [the `RegExp()` constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp):

```js
const zPrefixed = 'ZAR|ZBO|ZOL|ZLA|ZNY|ZSF|ZNK|ZHN|ZCH|ZMI|ZDF|ZGA|ZTB';
const others = 'EAC|MSC|SRC|IOE|LIN|WAC|NBC|YSC|SSC|ESC|WSC';

const pattern = new RegExp(
  String.raw`^(${others}|${zPrefixed})(\*|\d)\d{9}$`
);

const pattern2 = new RegExp(`^(${zPrefixed})$`);

console.config({ maximize: true });
console.log(pattern);
console.log(pattern2);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I can't modify the original declaration (e.g. split it up as you did here), it must remain intact.

Comment: @geneb. You can use `RegExp#source` for that. See updated answer.